# Views relationship not been added by code

Tags: commerce, views

Im trying to make a abandoned cart notification module, trying to relate my notification table with the commerde_order table by its order_id in views. Right now i have this in my hook_views_data

```
function commerce_abandoned_cart_notification_views_data(){
    $data = array();

    $data['commerce_abandoned_cart_notification']['table']['group']  = t('Commerce abandoned cart notification');

    $data['commerce_abandoned_cart_notification']['table']['join'] = array(
        'commerce_order' => array(
            'left_field' => 'order_id',
            'field' => 'order_id',
        ),
    );

    $data['commerce_abandoned_cart_notification']['table']['base'] = array(
        'field' => 'id',
        'title' => t('Commerce abandoned cart notification'),
        'help' => t('Commerce abandoned cart notification'),
    );

    $data['commerce_abandoned_cart_notification']['id'] = array(
        'title' => t('Notification ID', array(), array('context' => 'A Commerce abandoned cart notification internal ID')),
        'help' => t('The unique internal identifier of the notification.'),
        'field' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
            'click sortable' => TRUE,
        ),
        'filter' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
        ),
        'sort' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
        ),
    );

    $data['commerce_abandoned_cart_notification']['order_id'] = array(
        'title' => t('Order ID', array(), array('context' => 'A Commerce order ID')),
        'help' => t('The unique internal identifier of the order.'),
        'relationship' => array(
            'base' => 'commerce_order',
            'field' => 'order_id',
            'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
            'label' => t('Referencing order'),
        ),
        'field' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
            'click sortable' => TRUE,
        ),
        'filter' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
        ),
        'sort' => array(
            'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
        ),
    );

    return $data;
}
```

The problem is that when creating a view i do not see my relationship to commerce orders or viceversa, (the hook works because i can create a view of type commerce_abandoned_cart_notification and add some of its fields). I know there is a commerce_abandoned_cart_notification or commerce_notification module but they seem incomplete and/or abadoned

Should i use hook_views_data_alter to alter commerce_order relatations and add one to my custom table?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the module [Commerce Notification](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_notification)?